# can righ click on button that i use in GridView and open new tab

Tags: asp.net

I use below code in GridView for show each row information and when user click on this button(image) go to another page.
now i want to do it that when user right click on this button can open page in new tab

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" CommandName="Update" HeaderText="show" ImageUrl="~/Images/show.png" DataTextField="show" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of button field use hyperlink field. OR, if you need `CommandName`, you can use `TemplateColumn` and use `LinkButton` control. That will solve your problem.

Comment: i use `Templatefireld` and `LinkButton` but when i right click on it just see `Bookmark this Link`,`Copy Link Location`, `Inspect Element`